# Could anyone explain me about "geep" means?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I wanna to get means about **Geep**, i heard that is hybrid word, anything as you know.
if you can take one or more examples its better as you can.

Comment: Any context you'd like to share?

Comment: @snailboat , No

Comment: Everybody to clarify that, please pay attention @Khan's comments, that's OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geep is a an animal (also called sheep-goat chimera) produced by artificially combining embryos or DNA of a goat and a sheep. However if this animal results when a goat mates with a sheep, it is called sheep-goat hybrid (please refer to The Free Dictionary).

Comment: Dear @Khan, give me a favor, add an example please

Comment: Ali, per the said dictionary, the researchers in England reported the results of  the first chimeras in 1984 saying that the parts that grew from the sheep embryo were woolly and those that grew from the goat embryo were hairy.